# My PS3 Super Slim appears to be bricked, what can I do?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

My PS3 Super Slim is bricked. When I turn it on, it's fan works for 3 seconds then it's completely turned down, and there is no light.

I tried to change the power cable put its still not working. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! I am sorry, but it is practically impossible to know what is wrong on our end because we can't inspect your wiring, motherboard, or any other components to the device. It would be better to take it to a store that services electronics to figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Though this is late, I am going to answer anyway.

**Take it to a computer repair store**

We can't know what is wrong really, since computers and consoles are such complex machines we can't single the cause down without looking and inspecting the machine in person. As I recommended in my comment, take it to a computer repair store or GameStop and see if they can fix it or replace it.